# SQL LEFT JOIN "JOIN expression is not supported"

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

This question relates to one I raised here [SQL help in finding missing operations](http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,37840.0.html) on the Sparx website. They suggested I try StackOverflow so here I am. I had tried to do a lot of research on the problem before posting on the Sparx website. I have slightly tweaked it to make it more of a general SQL issue than fixed to the tool that I am using.

I am not an SQL guru so please be kind to me!

**The situation**
I have 2 tables that has the following elements

`Table t_object`
`--------------`
`Object_ID   AutoNumber`
`Object_Type Text`
`Name        Text`
`ParentID    Number`

`Table t_operation`
`-----------------`
`OperationID AutoNumber`
`Object_ID   Number`
`Name        Text`

The table t_object contains lots of different types of items. The Object_ID is the unique key. The items that I am interested are where Object_Type = 'class' OR 'activity' OR 'activityparameter'. The Name is the name of the item. The ParentID is only applicable to 'activityparameter' items and is the Object_ID of the 'activity' that the 'activityparameter' belongs to.

The table t_operation contains all operations belonging to a class. The OperationID is the unique key. The Object_ID is how this operation is linked to its class in t_object.

**The problem**
In our system all classes have an equally named activity and all operations belonging to a class have an equally named activityparameter belonging to the activity.

I am trying to find **erroneous** entries where operation MyOp in class MyClass does **not** have an equally named activityparameter MyOp in activity MyClass.

Using the test data below

`t_object`
`+-----------+-------------------+-------+----------+`
`| Object_ID |       Object_Type |  Name | ParentID |`
`+-----------+-------------------+-------+----------+`
`|         1 |             Class |    c1 |        0 |`
`|         2 |             Class |    c2 |        0 |`
`|         3 |          Activity |    c1 |        0 |`
`|         4 |          Activity |    c2 |        0 |`
`|         5 | ActivityParameter | MyOp1 |        3 |`
`|         6 | ActivityParameter | MyOp2 |        3 |`
`|         7 | ActivityParameter | MyOp3 |        3 |`
`|         8 | ActivityParameter | MyOp1 |        4 |`
`|         9 | ActivityParameter | MyOp2 |        4 |`
`+-----------+-------------------+-------+----------+`

`t_operation`
`+-------------+-----------+-------+`
`| OperationID | Object_ID |  Name |`
`+-------------+-----------+-------+`
`|           1 |         1 | MyOp1 |`
`|           2 |         1 | MyOp2 |`
`|           3 |         2 | MyOp1 |`
`|           4 |         2 | MyOp2 |`
`|           5 |         2 | MyOp3 |`
`|           6 |         2 | MyOp4 |`
`+-------------+-----------+-------+`

The above tables represent the following

`Operation          c1::MyOp1 (from class c1)`
`Operation          c1::MyOp2 (from class c1)`
`Operation          c2::MyOp1 (from class c2)`
`Operation          c2::MyOp2 (from class c2)`
`Operation          c2::MyOp3 (from class c2)`
`Operation          c2::MyOp4 (from class c2)`
`Activity parameter c1::MyOp1 (from activity c1)`
`Activity parameter c1::MyOp2 (from activity c1)`
`Activity parameter c1::MyOp3 (from activity c1)`
`Activity parameter c2::MyOp1 (from activity c2)`
`Activity parameter c2::MyOp2 (from activity c2)`

We can see the following errors

`Operation c2::MyOp3 has no equivalent activity parameter`
`Operation c2::MyOp4 has no equivalent activity parameter`
`Activity parameter c1::MyOp3 has no equivalent operation`

For the purpose of this question I am not interested in the final error. When I get the SQL query for "operation class::operation has no equivalent activity parameter" then I will have the logic to do the reverse.

I tried the SQL query (I am using Access and also MySQL). Note, text searches are case insensitive. The 2 IDs at the end of the SELECT should be equal if the activity parameter belongs to the mentioned activity. If they are different then the returned activity parameter belongs to a different activity. This acts as a quick cross-check.

```
SELECT o_class.name, o_operation.name, o_activity.name, o_actparam.name, o_activity.object_ID AS "activity ID", o_actparam.parentID AS "belongs to activity ID"  
FROM  
(((  
t_object o_class  
INNER JOIN t_object o_activity ON  
    (   o_activity.name = o_class.name  
       AND  
       o_class.object_type = 'class'  
       AND  
       o_activity.object_type = 'activity'  
    )  
)  
INNER JOIN t_operation o_operation ON o_operation.object_id = o_class.object_id)  
LEFT JOIN t_object o_actparam ON  
    (   o_actparam.name = o_operation.name  
        AND  
        o_actparam.object_type = 'activityparameter'  
        AND  
        o_actparam.parentid = o_activity.object_id  
    )  
)  
WHERE  
    o_actparam.name is NULL  
ORDER BY  
    o_class.name, o_operation.name, o_activity.name, o_actparam.name, o_activity.object_ID, o_actparam.parentID
```

The above aims to get a class, then an activity with the same name, then all operations belonging to the class, then **for each** operation **try and find** an activity parameter in this activity with the same name. Any that didn't match should return NULL (since it is a LEFT JOIN) and so the WHERE statement shows the operations that didn't have a related activityparameter, i.e. the errors.

The above does not work; I get a "JOIN expression not supported".

If I take out the "o_actparam.parentid = o_activity.object_id" then it returns no results at all. **This is clearly wrong.** I believe this is because the LEFT JOIN matches on the first expression, i.e. "o_actparam.name = o_operation.name", then applies any other expressions to that result. So it returns 10 rows (one NULL for c2::MyOp4) but the 2nd expression (o_actparam.object_type = 'activityparameter') then throws away the NULL (c2::MyOp4). Then all 9 results are thrown away by the WHERE clause.

If I change the LEFT JOIN to

```
LEFT JOIN t_object o_actparam ON  
    (   o_actparam.name = o_operation.name  
        AND  
        (   o_actparam.object_type = 'activityparameter'  
            OR  
            o_actparam.object_type is NULL  
        )  
    )  
)
```

then I get the result

```
c2::MyOp4
```

It has failed to find c2::MyOp3. This is because operation c2::MyOp3 matches activityparmater c1::MyOp3 (same activity parameter name even though it belongs to the wrong class/activity c1). The LEFT JOIN comparison ignores the class/activity. Remember, if I put the 'o_actparam.parentid = o_activity.object_id' check then I get "JOIN expression not supported".

If I change the WHERE (and keep the above LEFT JOIN) to

```
WHERE  
    o_actparam.parentid <> o_activity.object_id  
OR  
    o_actparam.parentid is NULL
```

then I get the result

```
c1::MyOp1
c1::MyOp2
c2::MyOp1
c2::MyOp2
c2::MyOp3
c2::MyOp4
```

It is now finding lots of wrong items since the same activityparameter name exists in different activities. The WHERE is too late to throw away items, however, putting the parentid in the LEFT JOIN gave me the "JOIN expression is not supported" error.

In my research I noticed that I could concatenate the expressions in an ON clause, e.g.

```
LEFT JOIN t_object o_actparam ON  
    o_actparam.name + o_actparam.object_type + o_actparam.parentid = o_operation.name + 'activityparameter' + o_activity.object_id  
)
```

The idea here is that if the LEFT JOIN works on the first expression then filters on any subsequent ones then putting them all as one would do what I wanted. It also has the benefit of not requiring "OR xxx is NULL" all over the place. It also reinforces what I am looking for, the combination of name, object type and parent. Naturally the above didn't work (or I wouldn't be asking here); it still gave the same "JOIN expression not supported". Again, removing the "parentID" aspect gave wrong results.

I hope I have given a detailed situation, test cases, expected answers, my reasonings and my research to show this is not just a "I couldn't be bothered to work it out myself, please help". I have spent days googling and trying out SQL but, as I said, I am not an SQL expert.

Is someone able to help me here?
Thanks
Darren

Comment: I have found the answer so am posting it here in case someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer so am posting it here in case someone finds it useful. Thanks Sandra for your help.

The answer is that my problem LEFT JOIN was trying to access entries in earlier tables but it couldn't see them because I referred to 2 different tables. I am not an SQL expert so I don't know the correct terminology or exactly why.

Anyway, the solution is to place all previous tables into a subquery so that it then gets a new single table name.

Note, since I am using Access, I have been told that the parentheses after the ON part of the LEFT JOIN are essential since I am joining on a constant value ('activityparameter').

The changes needed were to insert

```
(SELECT * FROM
```

before the first 2 tables. Note that this required me to break the single line with 3 parentheses into 2 lines as the SELECT needed to go after the first parenthesis.

After that add an extra

```
) AS q1
```

after the 2 tables. In my final answer below I've indented this whole section and put a blank line before and after for clarity.

Then in my LEFT JOIN I refer to the old tables by adding **q1.** at the start of each reference.

The following query works perfectly and gives the results that I expected.

```
SELECT o_class.name, o_operation.name, o_activity.name, o_actparam.name, o_activity.object_ID AS "activity ID", o_actparam.parentID AS "belongs to activity ID"  
FROM  
(
    (SELECT * FROM
    ((  
    t_object o_class  
    INNER JOIN t_object o_activity ON  
        (   o_activity.name = o_class.name  
           AND  
           o_class.object_type = 'class'  
           AND  
           o_activity.object_type = 'activity'  
        )  
    )  
    INNER JOIN t_operation o_operation ON o_operation.object_id = o_class.object_id)  
    ) AS q1

LEFT JOIN t_object o_actparam ON  
    (   o_actparam.name = q1.o_operation.name  
        AND  
        o_actparam.object_type = 'activityparameter'  
        AND  
        o_actparam.parentid = q1.o_activity.object_id  
    )  
)  
WHERE  
    o_actparam.name is NULL  
ORDER BY  
    o_class.name, o_operation.name, o_activity.name, o_actparam.name, o_activity.object_ID, o_actparam.parentID
```